# How do I determine what exception caused Test Explorer to crash?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, visual-studio-2017, test-explorer

When I ran tests in prior versions of Visual Studio Test Explorer and there was a problem that caused the build runner to crash (such as `AccessViolationException`, `StackOverflowException`, `OutOfMemoryException`, etc), it would output a message displaying the exception type thrown and how to enable a log to get more details.

With Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition version 15.3.2 and .NET Core 1.0, when there is a crash all that is shown in the Test Output is:

> [8/30/2017 3:03:42 AM Error] The active Tests Run was aborted.
>
> [8/30/2017 3:03:42 AM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 1030 run (0:41:12.5762484) ==========

How can I determine what type of exception caused the build runner to crash (preferably with a stack trace)?

**NOTE:** I have opened an [issue with NUnit](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/381) during this investigation asking about how to determine *which* tests are causing the crash. I have already isolated (and worked around) 2 of the causes.

1. [.NET Core 2.0 crashes fatally when a `Debug.Assert` fails](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1022)
2. [The test runner was running out of virtual memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45944741) due to running under 32 bit.

But there is still at least one more issue causing a crash. I am trying to work out why the test runner crashes in Visual Studio 2017 but does not crash on the command line.

Also note that this particular crash does not happen when running on .NET Framework, so suggestions to use command line tools that don't support .NET Core 1.0 or .NET Core 2.0 (such as `vstest.console.exe`) are not helpful.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition version 15.3.2. And no, I am not using Resharper.

Comment: Any information in EventViewer that can help?

Comment: You have enabled logging? [MSDN: How to enable Unit Test explorer logs?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2012/03/01/how-to-enable-ute-logs/), more info [on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38621931/495455). Surely that will give you clues..

Comment: @NightOwl888 did you tried to  check the event viewer logs to see if there are any suspicious Error entries under `Windows Logs -> Application.` and in the process  of checking through command line did you able to see the log file using `Diag/` argument ?

Comment: @NightOwl888 there is a similar round of issue was rasied on [Visual Stuio 2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/89554/visual-studio-2017-unit-testing-net-core-fails-to.html)

Comment: @NightOwl888 You should analyze the crash dump. You can start from DebugDiag https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924 and if you want to go deeper use WinDbg.

Comment: @KostyaK - without access to Microsoft private symbols (pdb's) you cant uncover much. Better off sending the Dump to Microsoft PSS/CSS support. The Test Explorer Logs will probably show the smoking gun as per my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This have been several reported issues similar to this. It appears to be a bug with the Entity Framework Core that hasn't been fixed yet. It was also a problem in the .NET Core command-line (CLI) that's been fixed.

**Open issue**

[SqlLite.FunctionalTests sometimes fail on Ubuntu #8642](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8642) also has the same issue, different app type, but same issue. The OP is also having difficulty finding a trace of the error.

```
The active test run was aborted. Reason: 
null
```

The current open one has been marked as blocked:

> Discussed again in triage and decided that we need to get more info
>   from the test runner. Commented on [Microsoft/vstest#527](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/527) asking for
>   more info. Marking as blocked for now until we get some info from the
>   vstest team.

**Closed on 22 Jun**

There is a [The reason why the test run was aborted is not indicated. #527](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/527)
 which was marked as a duplicate of:
 [Show the test which crashed the test run (test explorer) #627](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/627)

The solutions being

> This is fixed in latest dev builds of dotnet-cli
>   2.0.0-preview1-005963. Download it from https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/release/2.0.0/dotnet-dev-win-x64.latest.zip.
>
> We have also fixed it for VS. Will update when a build with fix is
>   available.
>
> Note: issue will show for netcoreapp2.0 due to [dotnet/cli#6535](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6535).

And

> .../ fix is available in VS15.3.0 preview2.

**How to get logs of the crash**

Apart from ensuring you've enable diagnostics (which I'm sure you have), or running it on a console.

A [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/627#issuecomment-310286859) from the github issue *Show the test which crashed the test run (test explorer) #627*

> Can you enable --diag:log.txt switch to get more logs and analyze
>   log.txt and log.*.host.txt for more details?

**Closed as no repro**

[No explanation of aborting test when a static constructor throws exception. #334](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/334) reported the same issues:

```
The active test run was aborted. Reason:
```

No reason.

It was closed as no repro.

---

To address the need to run the nunit tests on the main thread [Running unit tests with a main loop](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1227).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. I am not using Entity Framework at all, so that is probably not it. I have discovered a cause, though. Some of the tests are running NUnit asserts on background threads, which throw exceptions. These exceptions are completely ignored in .NET Framework, but in .NET Core 2.0 it is causing a fatal crash. Either way, I need to work out how to marshal the failure back over to the main thread - any ideas?